# How play 3D movies on PC (Windows)

Tags: windows-7, video, mp4, 3d

I have a 3D mp4 video file. When I open it with KMplayer/POT player, They display two instances of the film side-by-side. How can I watch it like a normal 2D video?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a player that is made for 3d formats. One like Stereoscopic Player.

http://3dtv.at/Index_en.aspx

Answer (score 2):

1. ->Open Main Menu
2. ->video
3. ->3D video Mode
4. ->Enable/Disable 3D video mode